# Form field is being rejected and I can not figure out why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Hmm, hope this question is clear.

I have an old app I'm porting over to Rails 5.

I have a form using a special method "create_shift" to handle it that is breaking at the line indicated below (note: create_shift is part of the original code I am porting over)...i've included the console error message after the attempt...

Here is the error...

```
vs.attributes=(assignment_params) #fixme: if i try this line I get...

# ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'contact_id' for VolunteerShift.
#   from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.7.2/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:48:in `_assign_attribute'
```

Here is the form...

views/assignments/_form.html.erb  (contact_id is near the middle)

```
<%= form_for @assignment, :url => @my_url, remote: true do |f| %>
  

  <div class="">
    <div class="modal-body  d-flex">
      <div class="col-sm-8 border-right">
        <section id="location-date-time-notes" class="flex">
          <% if @assignment.errors.any? %>
            <div id="error_explanation">
              <h2><%= pluralize(@assignment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this assignment from being saved:</h2>
              <ul>
                <% @assignment.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                  <li><%= message %></li>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
            </div>
          <% end %>

          <!--VOLUNTEER SHIFT-->
          <!--TODO: make this a partial under field_for-->
          <%= f.fields_for :volunteer_shift do |builder| %>
            <%= render 'assignments/volunteer_shift_fields', vs: builder %>
          <% end %>
          <!--TODO: Volunteer Shift end -->
          
<!--          Set Date field has to be here not in the partial-->
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :set_date, "Date" %>
            <%= f.text_area(:set_date) %>
          </div>

          <div id="time-row" class="d-flex flex-row">
            <label for="assignment_time" class="col-sm-3 p-2">
              <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Time:
            </label>
            <div class="col- p-2">
              <div class="myStartTime"  id="start_time_<%= @assignment.id %>">
                <%= f.time_select :start_time %>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col- p-2"><i class="fa fa-arrows-h fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 p-2">
              <div class="myEndTime"  id="end_time_<%= @assignment.id %>">
                <%= f.time_select :end_time %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex flex-row">
            <label for="assignment_notes" class="col-sm-3 p-2">
              <i class="fa fa-clipboard fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Notes:
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-9 p-2">
              <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                <span> Notes only get saved if a contact is assigned the shift, and get removed when the contact is removed from the shift.</span>
                <div class="">
                  <%= f.label :notes %>
                  <%= f.text_area :notes %>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-4">

        <!-- Contact Section-->
        <div id="contact_section">
          <% if @assigned_contacts &&  @assigned_contacts.length > 0 %>
            <h2>Previously Assigned Contacts</h2>
            <% @assigned_contacts.each do |c| %>
              <%= label_tag "assigned_contacts[#{c.id}]", "Are you sure you want to remove the currently scheduled volunteer, #{c.display_name} (##{c.id}), from the assignment(s)?" %>
              <%= check_box_tag "assigned_contacts[#{c.id}]", "replace", @replaced_contacts.include?(c.id) %>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
          <input id="contact_element_prefix" name="contact_element_prefix" type="hidden" value="contact">
          <div class="name large flex-row">
            <%= f.label :contact_id %>
            <%= f.text_field :contact_id %>  #<==============================================CONTACT_ID
          </div>

          <div id="display-contact" class="d-flex flex-row">
            <% if f.object.contact_id %>
              <%= render partial: 'contacts/contact_display', locals: { contact:f.object.contact} %>
            <% else %>
              <div>no contact attatched- _form.html called</div>
              <%#= link_to 'Show Contact', contact_path(f.object.contact_id),  remote: true %>
            <% end %>
          </div>

          <!--    FIXME: replace this logic stack with AJAX-->
          <%#= contact_field("@obj", "contact_id",
        :locals => {:options => {
        :object_name => f.object_name.to_s,
        :field_name => 'contact_id',
        :on_display => 'display_disciplinary_notes(); display_contact_notes();'
        }}
                      ) %>
          <%= f.label :closed, "Is this slot closed?" %>
          <%= f.check_box :closed %>

          <!--Contact Section END-->

          <!--Attendance / Call Status start-->
          <% if f.object.id && f.object.contact_id %>

            <div class="flex-row">
              <div class="col-25"><label for="assignment_attendance_type_id">Attendance:</label></div>
              <div class="col-75"><%= select(f.object_name,
                                             "attendance_type_id",
                                             AttendanceType.all.sort_by(&:id).collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] },
                                             :include_blank => true) %></div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-row">
              <div class="col-25"><label for="assignment_call_status_type_id">Call status:</label></div>
              <div class="col-75"><%= select(f.object_name,
                                             "call_status_type_id",
                                             ([["not called yet", ""]] + CallStatusType.all.sort_by(&:id).collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }),
                                             :include_blank => false) %></div>

            </div>
          <% end %>
          <!-- Attendance / Call Status End-->

          <!-- LOCK VERSION-->
          <div class="flex-row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <%= f.label :lock_version %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <%= f.number_field :lock_version %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- LOCK end-->
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
      <div class="edit_icons d-flex flex-row">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
          <!--            <a href="/assignments/edit/<%#= skedj.current.id %>" title="split"><i class="fa fa-share-alt-square fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Split</a>-->
          <!--            <a href="/assignments/copy/<%#= skedj.current.id %>" title="copy"><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Copy</a>-->
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
          <%#= link_to '<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>Edit'.html_safe, edit_assignment_path,  remote: true%>
          <!--            <a href="#" onclick="reassign(<%#= skedj.current.id %>); return false;" title="reassign"> <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Reassign</a>-->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><%= f.submit "Submit" %></button>
        <!--              <input id="assignment_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Update">-->
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

<% end %>
```

Here is the partial in that form

assignment/volunteer_shift_fields

```
<div class="name large flex-row">
  <%= vs.label :volunteer_shift %>
</div>
<div id="volunteer_shift" class="d-flex flex-row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 p-2">
    <div id="volunteer_shift" class="text-right">
      <div class="field">
        <%= vs.label :volunteer_task_type_id %>
        <%= vs.select 'volunteer_task_type_id', options_from_collection_for_select([VolunteerTaskType.new(:description => ""),  VolunteerTaskType.instantiables.effective_on(Date.today)].flatten, "id", "description")  %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= vs.label :roster_id %>
        <%= vs.select 'roster_id', options_from_collection_for_select([Roster.new(:name => ""), Roster.all].flatten, "id", "name") %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= vs.label :program_id %>
        <%= vs.select 'program_id', options_from_collection_for_select([Program.new(:name => ""), Program.where(:volunteer => true)].flatten, "id", "name")%>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= vs.label :set_description, "Description" %>
        <%= vs.text_area(:set_description) %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

volunteer_events_controller

```
class VolunteerEventsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_volunteer_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

...

  def create_shift # FIXME: evil brought over from original code base
    ve = nil
    if !params["id"].blank?
      ve = VolunteerEvent.find(params["id"])
    else
      if params["assignment"]["volunteer_shift_attributes"]["roster_id"].blank? || params["assignment"]["set_date"].blank?
        ve = VolunteerEvent.new # won't save
      else
        ve = Roster.find_by_id(params["assignment"]["volunteer_shift_attributes"]["roster_id"]).vol_event_for_date(params["assignment"]["set_date"])
      end
    end

    vs = ve.volunteer_shifts.new

    vs.stuck_to_assignment = vs.not_numbered = true

binding.pry
    vs.attributes=(assignment_params) #if i try this line I get...

    # ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'contact_id' for VolunteerShift.
    #   from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.7.2/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:48:in `_assign_attribute'


    binding.pry
...
end

...
  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_volunteer_event
      @volunteer_event = VolunteerEvent.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
      def assignment_params
        params.require(:assignment).permit(:action, :controller, :title, :set_date, :date, :date_range, :volunteer_shift_id, :contact_id, :start_time, :end_time, :start, :end, :attendance_type_id, :notes, :call_status_type_id, :closed, :lock_version, :color, :description, :contact_element_prefix, :lock_versions, :commit, volunteer_shift_attributes: [:volunteer_task_type_id,:roster_id,:program_id,:set_description,:id, :destroy])
        # params.require(:volunteer_event).permit(:description, :volunteer_default_event_id, :date, :notes, :nowalkins)
      end
    def volunteer_event_params
      params.require(:volunteer_event).permit(:description, :volunteer_default_event_id, :date, :notes, :nowalkins)
    end
end
```

Heck here's even the model associations

```
class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
  # attr_accessor :volunteer_event ,:contact_id #why is this here???
  # attr_accessor :redirect_to
  belongs_to :volunteer_shift
  has_one :volunteer_task_type, :through => :volunteer_shift, :source => :volunteer_task_type
  belongs_to :contact ,optional: true
  validates_presence_of :volunteer_shift #belongs_to takes care of this now
  validates_associated :volunteer_shift
  belongs_to :attendance_type
  belongs_to :call_status_type
  validates_presence_of :set_date, :if => :volshift_stuck #belongs_to takes care of this now??
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :volunteer_shift, allow_destroy: true #4 Nested form

  delegate :set_date, :set_date=, :to => :volunteer_shift
  delegate :set_description, :set_description=, :to => :volunteer_shift
...
end
```

```
class VolunteerEvent < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :volunteer_default_event
  validates_presence_of :date
  has_many :volunteer_shifts, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :resources_volunteer_events, :dependent => :destroy
  validates_associated :volunteer_shifts
...
end
```

```
class VolunteerShift < ApplicationRecord
  validates_presence_of :roster_id
  validates_presence_of :end_time
  validates_presence_of :start_time
  has_many  :assignments
  belongs_to :volunteer_default_shift
  belongs_to :volunteer_task_type
  belongs_to :roster
  belongs_to :volunteer_event
  belongs_to :program
  has_many :contact_volunteer_task_type_counts, :primary_key => 'volunteer_task_type_id', :foreign_key => 'volunteer_task_type_id' #:through => :volunteer_task_type

...
end
```

I hope that is not too confusing. So it seems the code breaks at...

```
    vs.attributes=(assignment_params) #fixme: if i try this line I get...

    # ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'contact_id' for VolunteerShift.
    #   from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.7.2/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:48:in `_assign_attribute'
```

So I am wondering...how do get contact_id to register?

Not sure if this helps but i'll add it. The params that this is receiving look like so....

```
> [2] pry(#<VolunteerEventsController>)> params
> => <ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "assignment"=><ActionController::Parameters
> {"volunteer_shift_attributes"=><ActionController::Parameters
> {"volunteer_task_type_id"=>"41", "roster_id"=>"7", "program_id"=>"9",
> "set_description"=>"so sick of this database"} permitted: false>,
> "set_date"=>"2021-01-11", "start_time(1i)"=>"2021",
> "start_time(2i)"=>"11", "start_time(3i)"=>"11",
> "start_time(4i)"=>"08", "start_time(5i)"=>"00",
> "end_time(1i)"=>"2021", "end_time(2i)"=>"11", "end_time(3i)"=>"11",
> "end_time(4i)"=>"09", "end_time(5i)"=>"00", "notes"=>"Fonso in Matrix
> Nov", "contact_id"=>"166574", "closed"=>"0", "lock_version"=>"0"}
> permitted: false>, "contact_element_prefix"=>"contact",
> "commit"=>"Submit", "controller"=>"volunteer_events",
> "action"=>"create_shift"} permitted: false> [3]
> pry(#<VolunteerEventsController>)>
```

The older app did not have strong_params so that wasn't an issue then. But I suspect some odd coding around contact_id in the old app.

What can i do to get this line working with contact_id...

```
vs.attributes=(assignment_params)
```

...or at least the intended outcome?

Should there be some sort of attr_accessor for contact_id placed in volunteer_shift model or on some higher level?

Is there some weird hack or rails magic I can use. Lol, that sounds nuts but I suspect that may have been what the old app did.

Please let me know if i need to add anything to this post like model associations,views or anything else, i will gladly oblige.

Thank you for your time.

UPDATE:

Now if I rewrite the params method like so...

```
      def volunteer_event_params

>         params.require(:volunteer_event).permit(:action, :controller, :title, :set_date, :date, :date_range, :volunteer_shift_id,
> :contact_id, :start_time, :end_time, :start, :end,
> :attendance_type_id, :notes, :call_status_type_id, :closed,
> :lock_version, :color, :description, :contact_element_prefix,
> :lock_versions, :commit, volunteer_shift_attributes:
> [:volunteer_task_type_id,:roster_id,:program_id,:set_description,:id,
> :destroy])

      end
```

I get this error

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing - param is missing or the value is empty: volunteer_event:
```

Digging with Pry, I see I get these params...

```
> [1] pry(#<VolunteerEventsController>)> params
> => <ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "assignment"=><ActionController::Parameters
> {"volunteer_shift_attributes"=><ActionController::Parameters
> {"volunteer_task_type_id"=>"41", "roster_id"=>"7", "program_id"=>"9",
> "set_description"=>"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"} permitted:
> false>, "set_date"=>"2021-01-11", "start_time(1i)"=>"2021",
> "start_time(2i)"=>"11", "start_time(3i)"=>"11",
> "start_time(4i)"=>"08", "start_time(5i)"=>"00",
> "end_time(1i)"=>"2021", "end_time(2i)"=>"11", "end_time(3i)"=>"11",
> "end_time(4i)"=>"09", "end_time(5i)"=>"00",
> "notes"=>"bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb",
> "contact_id"=>"166574", "closed"=>"0", "lock_version"=>"0"} permitted:
> false>, "contact_element_prefix"=>"contact", "commit"=>"Submit",
> "controller"=>"volunteer_events", "action"=>"create_shift"} permitted:
> false> [2] pry(#<VolunteerEventsController>)>
```

Answer (score 0):

So to "fix" this in this situation (upgrading an old Rails 2.x app by porting code to a Rails 5.0 app)

Turn of strong params:

```
config.action_controller.permit_all_parameters = true
```

find more on this here...https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/configuring.html